# ASP.NET MVC4 Kendo UI grid update and delete problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

This is my first time working with Kendo Ui, and I'm facing problems trying to update and delete rows, both actions not working. 
I tried many solutions in vain.
So, I'll share with you, the view and controller that I'm using

View :

```
@model IEnumerable<Lawhati.Fournisseur>
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", "Fournisseurs")
</p>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).
    Name("Fournisseurs").Columns(c =>
    {
        c.Bound(p => p.IdFournisseur);
        c.Bound(p => p.nomFournisseur);
        c.Bound(p => p.TelFournisseur);
        c.Bound(p => p.emailFournisseur);
        c.Command(cmd =>
        {
            cmd.Edit().HtmlAttributes(new { title = "Modifier" });
            cmd.Destroy().HtmlAttributes(new { title = "Supprimer" });
        }).Title("Administation");
    })
    .DataSource(d =>
       d.Ajax()
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.IdFournisseur); // Specify the property which is the unique identifier of the model
            model.Field(p => p.IdFournisseur).Editable(false); // Make the ProductID property not editable
        })
       .Update(update => update.Action("Edit", "Fournisseurs"))  // Action invoked when the user saves an updated data item
       .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Delete", "Fournisseurs")) // Action invoked when the user removes a data item
   )
   .Pageable()
)
```

Controller :

```
public class FournisseursController : Controller
{
    private ModelLawhatiContainer db = new ModelLawhatiContainer();

    // GET: Fournisseurs
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Fournisseur.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Fournisseurs/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Fournisseur fournisseur = db.Fournisseur.Find(id);
        if (fournisseur == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(fournisseur);
    }

    // GET: Fournisseurs/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Fournisseurs/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "IdFournisseur,nomFournisseur,emailFournisseur,password,username,TelFournisseur")] Fournisseur fournisseur)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Fournisseur.Add(fournisseur);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(fournisseur);
    }

    // GET: Fournisseurs/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Fournisseur fournisseur = db.Fournisseur.Find(id);
        if (fournisseur == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(fournisseur);
    }

    // POST: Fournisseurs/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "IdFournisseur,nomFournisseur,emailFournisseur,lastLogin,password,username,TelFournisseur")] Fournisseur fournisseur)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(fournisseur).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(fournisseur);
    }

    // GET: Fournisseurs/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Fournisseur fournisseur = db.Fournisseur.Find(id);
        if (fournisseur == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(fournisseur);
    }

    // POST: Fournisseurs/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Fournisseur fournisseur = db.Fournisseur.Find(id);
        db.Fournisseur.Remove(fournisseur);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }


  }
```

Comment: Did you check what error  you are getting in the browser console?

Comment: You're using an Ajax data source in your grid. So, your Delete and Update actions cannot return a View. They should return JSON. Also, you need to set the Editable property of the grid in order to make it editable. Check the Kendo Grid demos for help.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-inline

Comment: @ataravati Do I need to change Controller to make it returns JSON ?!

Comment: @ataravati I've been looking through the demo and still can't understand the meaning of this class SampleEntities and where I can create! 
this is my first time working with this technologie.